# Return unique user doesn't work with group_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm using the ajax datatable gem to display the client name and total points in a store. the store-clients table looks like this.

```
store_id
client_id
total_points
```

But as it will be a report, I don't want to show the same client twice, even to different stores. I am trying the following:

```rb
StoreClient.joins(:client).group(:client_id)
```

But I get this error: `column "store_clients.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

If I add the store_clients id the result is not as expected.

The expected would be:

```
client_id | store_id | total_points
   1           1          10
   1           2          20
   2           1          5
-----------------------------------
client_id | store_id | total_points
   1           1          10
   2           1          5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume initial result is an array store in instance variable `@result` you can get a unique result  like this:

```rb
@result.uniq {|o| o.client_id }
```